# HTML page assets in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I would like to have a static HTML page as a component in which I use WebBrowser component.
The main problem is.. I am having a hard time with my page assets like images and css/js files. when I put my page under src package, Do I need to put my assets folder inside my src package/folder?

What would be the best approach on this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best approach is to embed everything into the page. Codename One has a method within `WebBrowser` that allows you to convert files (e.g. images) to data URI's: `WebBrowser.createDataURI()`.

This isn't ideal but its by far the most portable solution. To statically create data URI's you can use a tool such as this: http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php

Comment: How about JS files or CSS files? should I do the same thing? and I am talking a large scale designs like including a couple of images for background and all other stuffs

Comment: There are other solutions e.g. see https://github.com/shannah/CN1-Charts where Steve effectively embedded HTML/JavaScript/CSS in a very elaborate way.
The main issue is with hierarchies which don't translate well to device paradigms.

Comment: I cant seem to get the workflow behind the chart component.
I just need it to be basic.. I would just like to build it in an IOS device. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand the question here? I was referencing Steve's work (and you can see some of his other projects too) as a point of reference to how elaborate HTML/JavaScript can be integrated into a Codename One project.